# How to read multiple .csv files and analyse the data?

Tags: python, csv

The following situation:

- movies.csv

  `movieId,title,genres`
- tags.csv

  `userId,movieId,tag,timestamp`

I want to get the tags from tags.csv and append to the dictionary containing a list where all the tags should be stored. The movieID should be identical so that the list can be appended. The list should also not have duplicates.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('movies1.csv'))

dict = {}
header = next(reader)
# Check file as empty
if header != None:
    for row in reader:
        key = row[0]
        value = {
        "id": row[0],
        "title": row[1][:-6],
        "year": row[1][-5:-1],
        "average_rating": 0,
        "ratings": [],
        "tags": [], #the list that should be filled with tags
        "genres": row[2].split('|')
        }
        dict[key] = value
tags={}
with open('tags1.csv', mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    header = next(reader)
    # Check file as empty
    if header != None:
        for col in reader:
            if col[1] == dict[key]['id']:
                dict[key]['tags'].append(col[2])


    print(dict)
```

My result:

I get all the tags for the last movie. The rest of the tags are just empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like `key` is carried over from the first loop, therefore only has the last value.  Aside, I strongly recommend using a variable name other than `dict` as this is overwriting the builtin.

Comment: You only ever check `if col[1] == dict[key]['id']:` which is the last `key` from your first loop. Note, `if header != None:` is pointless. `header` will never be `None`. `next(reader)` would throw a `StopIteration` error

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I removed it but still have the same outcome.

Comment: @IrisoftEducation yes, I said it was pointless and not doing anything. The problem is that you are always checking `if col[1] == dict[key]['id']:`. And `key` is always the last one from the previous loop

Comment: @AMC I also tried to add the the for loop ( right after the first one but got pretty much the same

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga so how do i get the key to iterate?

Comment: You don't need to. You just use `dict[col[1]]["tags"].append(col[2])`

Comment: still the same.

Answer (score 0):

So i made it work. I created a second Dictionary and that looped in both of them.

```
for tag in tags:
    for movie in dict:

        if tags[tag]['movieId'] == dict[movie]['id']:
            if tags[tag]['tag'] not in dict[movie]['tags']:
                dict[movie]['tags'].append(tags[tag]['tag'])
```